# How can I debug a (possible) Stack Overflow Error in C python extention?

Tags: python, c, stack-overflow

As the title says, I am making a python c extension that takes input data and performs a non linear regression and returns the result. Here is the project:

https://github.com/datajamesallen/pydrc

However when I feed it particular sets of data, the python instance will abort, and give me the following error:

```
[2]    abort python3
```

https://pastebin.com/YSbB5UVB

Most of the stuff in this error message is fairly low-level language stuff (for me) so I can't figure out how to debug it or understand what is going on. This is an issue because I can't catch the exception in python etc.

Comment: Please edit your question so that it is a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thanks!

Comment: In the crash dump frame 4 to 6 seems to be in your extension. I'm certain there are tools that can take the address and with a debug build can find out the exact line number (maybe a debug build of the extension will include it as well, I don't know).